# Python histogram from dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, histogram

I have a dictionary that looks liks this:

```
dict = {1092267: '0.187', 524292: '-0.350', 524293: '0.029', 524294: '0.216'}
```

So there is an id, and then a value that's inside a string (the real dictionary contains 10 000 of these id's). I want to make a histogram with on the x axis the absolute values of the values inside those strings from lets say 0-0.1, 0.1-0.2, 0.2-0.3 etc all the way to 0.9-1.0. The y axis should count the amount of occurences of the values within these ranges of 0-0.1 etc. 
How do I do this???

Answer (score 3):

You can use **`numpy.histogram`** to create the histogram's bins.
First of all, get the absolute values of all the dictionary's values (since ids are irrelevant).

```
dict_values = [abs(float(i)) for i in dict.values()]
```

Then, use **`numpy.histogram`** specifying the range of the values explicitly.

```
import numpy as np
hist = np.histogram(dict_values, range=(0.0,1.0))
```

Comment: `dict_values = [abs(float(i)) for i in dict.values()]` to get the values. You get the IDs right now.

Comment: Thanks, this works! Is there also a way to see how many of the values are within a certain range? So let's say I want to know how many values are above 0.7??

Comment: @Joel you can filter the `dict_values` like this: `num_wanted = len[i for i in dict_values if i > 0.7]`

Comment: @VHarisop That did not work. It said invalid syntax. However with the line you've suggested I did it like this: '    num = []
    for i in absvalues:
        if i>0.7:
            num.append(i)
        num_above = len(num)

Comment: @Joel i forgot to put parentheses around the list, try `len([i for i in dict_values if i > 0.7])`

Answer (score 0):

Without using numpy.histogram, you can try:

```
test = {1092267: '0.187', 524292: '-0.350', 524293: '0.029', 524294: '0.216'}

intervals = [(-2, 0.1), (0.1, 0.2), (0.2, 0.3), (0.3, 0.4)]
count = []

for inf, sup in intervals:
    count.append(len([x for x in test.values() if inf < float(x) < sup]))
```

Then, count, which is the histogram, will have [2, 1, 1, 0]. This way you can specify arbitrary ranges to define the bins. If you want to plot it, you can use matplotlib ([example here](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo_extended.html)).

1: http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo_extended.html